# Nginx excluding directory from redirect rules

Tags: nginx

I have the following .conf in Nginx

```
location / {

    if ($uri !~ ^/front/? ){
        include ez_params.d/ez_rewrite_params last;
    }

    include common_auth.conf.inc;

    location ~ ^/(index|index_(rest|cluster|treemenu_tags))\.php(/|$) {
    #bunch of rules here
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here here is excluding the /front/ folder from all EzPublish rewrite rules. However, not only does this not work, it even gives me an error while trying to load this file:

"nginx: [emerg] "include" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/staging-preview.conf:51
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

I found out that using the "if" is pretty much not done, see http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil , but I don't understand what I should do instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create individual location blocks and include/exclude whatever you want. You can repeat "includes" in each as needed

For example:

```
location ~ ^/front/? {
    # Here we only include the common_auth file
    include common_auth.conf.inc;
}
location ~ ^/(index|index_(rest|cluster|treemenu_tags))\.php(/|$) {
    # Here we also only include the common_auth file
    include common_auth.conf.inc;
    ....
}
location / {
    # Here we also include the common_auth file
    # As well as the ez_rewrite_params
    include ez_params.d/ez_rewrite_params;
    include common_auth.conf.inc;
}
```

Note that you don't use "last" for including files